# National Library of Scotland Tileserver

Tags: tiles, scotland

I am a novice, self-taught QGIS user (using v3.10.0) and I would like to integrate the National Library of Scotland (NLS) Tileserver API into QGIS, but I just can't crack it.

Tile server is https://nls.tileserver.com/

I am using CRS EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid - Projected

I would like to be able to switch to the API maps at varying zoom levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me if I add a new XYZ Tiles service in the Browser panel.

The URL is `https://nls.tileserver.com/nls/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg`

The tile layer uses EPSG:3857 but if your project CRS is 27700 then QGIS will reproject it on the fly. But be careful of trying to draw the whole world with a project CRS like 27700 because its not valid over the whole globe and QGIS can end up drawing nothing.

Here it is blended over an OSM background layer...

[image]

And here's the full config dialog:

[image]